# Dose NSTimer can be used in Today Extension (Widget)?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, today-extension

I want to use a NSTimer in Today Extension to refresh the widget, but I don't know dose this behaviour is legality?

I was make a demo use a NSTimer to counting and refresh the widget UI every 1 second, seem like it's work, but the problem is when user exit Notification Center, the timer is still running, When and Where should I stop the timer?

Comment: Still don't know is this behavior legality, but I find Apple doesn't add the flag NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE to NSTimer, So I think we can use NSTimer in Today Extension. And then I think it's a good way to start timer in viewWillAppear: and stop the timer in viewWillDisappear:, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can also confirm that this approach works well for me.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated:Bool) {
    // stop the timer here when notification center is closed
}
```

Interestingly, both `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` are both called together one after another (in that order) as soon as you start to swipe up to close the notification center.
This means that while notification center and your widget are still visible on the screen (if you keep your finger on the drag handle) `viewDidDisappear` is already called.

Comment: On a related note, when opening notification center, the order in which the relevant methods are called are `viewDidLoad` , `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` , `viewWillAppear` and all 3 are called every time the notification center is in a fully open state